# Alarm doesn't trigger the AlarmReveicer

Tags: android

I am coding a simple alarm test in android, but as mentionned in the title the AlarmReceiver isn't triggered !

i sought here for the solution but none of them worked since my code seems to be correct ...

here is my code :

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

    Button salarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.salarm);
    final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);

    salarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+(1000*5), pi);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm set, wait 5 sec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

Manifest file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidtest3"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidtest3.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="AlarmActivity"/>
    <receiver 
    android:exported = "true"
    android:name = "AlarmReceiver">
    </receiver> <!-- <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"/> aurait fait l'affaire --> 

</application>

</manifest>
```

AlarmReceiver Class :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "pending intent received !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

}
```

it would help if you could explain the any solution you suggest.

thanx

Comment: where is AlarmReceiver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely not happening because the time value is incorrect.  If you are going to use `RTC_WAKEUP` type alarms, get the time using `System.currentTimeMillis()` plus your additional time.  Right now you're using elapsed time, which is not the same as RTC wall clock time.

Comment: Now it's ok, the intent is received, first time it wasn't received at time but after like 30 sec (in the code I specified 5 secs), when I plugged off my phone, it's received normally, why ?????. 

also another problem, the device doesn't wake up !! when I set the alarm I make the device go on sleep, and it doesn't wake up after 5 sec... any suggestions ???

Comment: See your code vs. my answer.  You have a mismatch in parameters.  If you use `RTC_WAKEUP` the API is expecting you to specify the time of day.  If you want elapsed time, use `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`.  Also see the updated docs, starting with API 19 the alarm setting is in-exact by default.  If you need exact timing, you'll have to use a different call.

Comment: I did, use the `System.currentTimeMillis()` with `RTC_WAKEUP` my comment is the result of the modified code.

Comment: It's difficult to say why that would not cause it to fire.  The "inexact" version (default on API 19) will cause a wake up to be combined with others around the same time and could cause your alarm to be delayed at least by the same interval (not sure what that means for RTC based timers.)

Comment: Something else you may want to check is whether your `onReceive` is being triggered, but the UI is not fully waking up.  The `AlarmManager` will automatically hold a wake lock for the duration of time your `onReceive` is running; but, after you return from `onReceive`, the wake lock can be released and the device will go back to sleep.  So if your `onReceive` is triggering a UI component, but is not holding its own wake lock then you will not seen the UI fully wake up.